# Shell: grep the true value

Tags: shell, grep

When I use grep to get i value, it gave me two value. How can i get the true value?

for example:

vmdk

CID=abcdefgh

parentCID=12345678

Shell

```
CID=$(grep -i "CID"  "snapshot.vmdk" | cut -d'=' -f2)
echo "CID = $CID"
```

Result:

CID = abcdefgh

12345678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `-w` flag in your grep command like:

```
grep -w -i ...
```